# Returning member from struct without .get()

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

Let's say I have following structure

```
template<typenameT>
class Foo
{
  T value;
  public:
    // some public logic
}
```

all what I want on this point is being able to say

```
Foo<int> A;
```

and then get value out of `A` as if it ware "just value of type T" and use it as follows

```
int val1 = A;  // must correspond to int val1 = A.value
               // and
int& val2 = A; // must return reference of A.value and so on
```

I really don't want to user set/get because I am going to write such calls very often and want therefor simplify the code as much as possible.

Firstly I thought overloading = might help, but I didn't get it right. It works for the opposite with the assignment operator such as `Foo<int> A; int val = 1; A = val;`

EDIT: There is sure already answer on the web, but I couldn't find it under "assignment" keyword.

Comment: Are you asking about [user defined conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)?

Comment: can you clarify: Why are you not using an `int` ? What you describe very much sounds like one ;). Why no `get()` method? Why not make `value` public? (note that once you returned a non-const reference to the caller, encapsulation is already broken)

Comment: In most cases, defining implicit conversions is a very bad idea: you should very carefully consider whether a minor convenience is worth a major weakening of the type system (which makes your code more error-prone and harder to maintain). That said, there are cases where this makes sense.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I have additional logic witch tracks the state of the variable, for example `bool is_set;` or the number of calls for the variable. "No get" because I am going to call this wrapper thousand times inside the code base, and want to keep the things simple.

Comment: @user12700880 But as soon as you return the internal variable by reference, don't you lose that tracking?

Comment: what i meant is: once the caller has a non-const reference all your bookkeeping wont keep the caller from modifying the private member via that reference. If you need bookkeeping you better only allow const references (if you dont you can make it public as well)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes the tracking is lost as I do so, but it happens in defined scope (body of called function witch uses arguments to calculate stuff). So I actually only need "to take value" once per function call and then use it as much as wanted. On this point you might think, why I don't count the number of function calls. And the answer is that there are multiple functions using same argument.

Answer (score 5):

it seems you want to overload [user-defined conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) operators:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
  T value;
public:
    operator T () const { return value; }
    operator T& () { return value; }

    // some public logic
};
```

Comment: Oh yes, I does the purpose as I wanted it, but it  does not follow the "super clear" syntax as I wished to have. Therefor I am thinking that for the long run, as Konrad Rudolph mentioned in the comments, this approach is prone to errors and it also increases the amount of boilerplate. (especially when type names are getting crazy e.g. simple `std::vector<double>` is already to much for me to write over and over again). As result I might overthought my arguments are just stick with old good `.get();` and  `.set();` as they are constant in the code written complexity ;)

Comment: @user12700880 curious: why does this not follow "super clear" snytax?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I my opinion something such as `int a = A` (or even `auto a = A` if it is clear that I do not make copy of A and instead return value of member) is clearer then `auto a = (int)A`.

Comment: @user12700880 your assumption is wrong (btw in any case you should not use `(int)` to cast, but `static_cast`), the conversions in this answer are implicit, no need for explicit casting. Fwiw, if they were explicit the drawbacks outlined in comments above are much less of a problem.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks, I was really unaware about implicitly of conversion on this point. Now I am no longer sure if I better stick to `set() get()` or use user-defined conversion. Btw. the book keeping is not at all huge deal in the code as I mentioned in initial post. I always save state of the argument (`bool is_set;`) and in not yet implemented part of the code I might do some logic based on number of times argument was ".get()`ed" (called) by other functions. Your remarks really help me to go further, thank you.

Comment: @user12700880 you might want to accept this answer, because irrespective of what you actually do in your code, this is the answer for your question as it stands. All the fuzz in the comments was just trying to understand why you ask that question (and perhaps helped you to understand if what you asked for is a good idea)